# How can I retrieve a signal parameter with New-Style Syntax?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

Inside a custom button class I have a signal which emits when is dropped something into it. Here the relevant method:

```
class CustomButton

   linked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
   ...

   def dropEvent(self, e):
        print e.source().objectName()
        print self.objectName()
            # set the drop action as LinkAction
        e.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.LinkAction)
        # tell the QDrag we accepted it
        e.accept()
        #Emit linked signal with the drag object's name as parameter
        self.linked.emit( e.source().objectName() )
        return QtGui.QPushButton.dropEvent(self, QtGui.QDropEvent(QtCore.QPoint(e.pos().x(), e.pos().y()), e.possibleActions(), e.mimeData(), e.buttons(), e.modifiers()))
```

In otherhand, outside the class, in the main application I'm creating a slot, and a way to connect it to the signal.

```
#The slot (actually is just a python callable)
def on_link(self):
    input = self.sender().objectName()[4:]
    print input
    #I need to print the name of the other object emitted as str parameter in the signal....

#Instance of custom button
custom_button.linked.connect( lambda: on_link( custom_button )  )
```

At this point I already know that I can get the `sender()` of the signal, however, I don't know how to get the parameter of `self.linked.emit( e.source().objectName() )`. I just know that first I have to change first this: linked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str), but don't know how to write the connection or the slot and retrieve the `e.source().objectName()` in the emit signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current design of the slot looks very confusing. At first glance, it looks like an instance method, but it is actually just a module-level function with a fake `self` parameter.

I would suggest something simpler, and more explicit, like this:

```
class CustomButton(QtGui.QPushButton):
    linked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, str)

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        ...
        self.linked.emit(self.objectName(), event.source().objectName())
        return QtGui.QPushButton.dropEvent(self, event)

def on_link(btn_name, src_name):
    print btn_name, src_name

custom_button.linked.connect(on_link)
```

An alternative design would be to send the objects, instead of their names:

```
    linked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object, object)
    ...
    self.linked.emit(self, event.source())

def on_link(button, source):
    print button.objectName(), source.objectName()
```